# Insert a child element without using appendChild?

Tags: javascript, dom

Supose i have this HTML code:

```
<div id='my-id'>
   <button> ClickMe </button>
</div>
```

And i want to append a new button, without using appendChild function (just curiosity). Is there any way to do that? Something like:

```
var div = document.getElementById('my-id')
document.createElement('button').parentNode(div)
//That doesn't work.
```

How appendChild works? It changes some element's property or what? Where can i find that information?

Thanks and sorry my bad english :)

Comment: You need a method to add the newly-created element to DOM. These methods are for example [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) and [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore), [`replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) and `options.add()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other functions that insert elements into the DOM, such as `insertBefore`, but you do need to use one of the provided methods.

> How appendChild works? It changes some element's property or what?

That's an implementation detail that is up to the individual browser.

> Where can i find that information?

For open source browsers you could examine their source code (which is usually written in C rather than JavaScript).

Comment: So there is no way of append an element to another element without using Javascript's appendChild/insertBefore...
That solves my question. Thank you!